# audio.currentTime resets to zero when I try to give it a value

Tags: javascript

I want to give the value of audio.currentTime just to test because it doesn't work in more complex code, but the value only changes for a moment and resets to zero

I tried checking after loadmetadata, but the console still outputs 0

Code:

```
audio = document.querySelector('.audio');

let songIndex;

// Init song
fetch(music_default_url)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        dataLength = data.length;
        songIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (dataLength));
        loadSong(data[songIndex]);
        console.log('DATA DOWNLOADED');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })

// Load song
function loadSong(track) {
    
    title.innerHTML = track.data.title; // Title
    artist.innerHTML = track.data.artist; // Artist
    audio.src = "/" + track.data.path.replace(/\\/g, "/"); // Audio source

    audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () {
        console.log('audio.duration: ' + audio.duration)
        if (audio.duration >= 30) {
            
            audio.currentTime = 30;
            console.log('CurrentTime: ' + audio.currentTime) 

        } else {
            console.log('duration < 30')
        }
    });

    currentTimeBlock.innerHTML = timeCalc(audio.currentTime); // Time block calc
    let previewPath = "/" + track.data.coverImage.replace(/\\/g, "/");
    previewImg.style.background = `url("${previewPath}")`; // Preview download
    
    // download metadata
    audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        songDuration.innerHTML = timeCalc(audio.duration); 
    };
}
```